# Can I Use Long Manfrotto QR Plates on a short head?

Tags: hardware

I've been considering whether to buy the [701HDV](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Manfrotto-701HDV-Professional-Fluid-Video/dp/B001D2LJ3Q/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1357331301&sr=1-1) or the [502AH](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Manfrotto-Pro-Fluid-Video-Neiger/dp/B006TZE0UQ/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1357331270&sr=8-1).

I've pretty much settled on the 502AH for its superior drag quality, but one thing a lot of people do not consider is the type of Quick Release (QR) plate they use.

The 701HDV and 501HDV both use the 501PL-type plate. The 502AH on the other hand uses 504PLONG plates, which are significantly bigger.

I have found out that you can use short plates on a "long" head by looking [here](http://www.dvinfo.net/forum/tripod-sticks-heads/507616-manfrotto-long-short-plates.html), but I'm not sure if I can put long plates on a "short" head.

The reason I ask is that I have a few short plates left over from an older tripod that *should* fit in the 502AH, and if I buy a [non-Manfrotto-branded QR adapter](http://www.calumetphoto.co.uk/eng/product/calumet_quick_release_video_head_adapter/ck9007) for something else, I can only find short plates.

So, can I use the long plate that comes with the 502AH with a short head or short QR adapter?

From looking at photos I can't see why not, but there's always a chance that it doesn't. Does anyone know for sure?

Comment: Did you try contacting Manfrotto directly? Here is their contact page: http://www.manfrotto.com/About+Us/Contact+Us/

Answer (score 1):

I have used the long plates on a shorter head.  Using it from a larger tripod on the monopod with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this will work fine. Many people prefer the longer plates because it allows you to balance a long lens.